# Value of type 'Query' has no member 'getDocument'

Tags: swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I know there are some answers to this question in the Internet, but I don't understand them. This is the Errorcode which I get if I run this code:

> Value of type 'Query' has no member 'getDocument'

```
let docRef = myDataBase.collection("LogIn Codes").whereField("Code", isEqualTo: code)

docRef.getDocument { (document, error) in
    let result = Result {
      try document?.data(as: KlassenCodes.self)
    }
    switch result {
    case .success(let KlassenCodes):
        if let KlassenCodes = KlassenCodes {
            KlassenCodes.id = document!.documentID // Get the ID of the Document as we might need it later
            codeArray.append(KlassenCodes) // Save the document into your array
        } else {
            // A nil value was successfully initialized from the DocumentSnapshot,
            // or the DocumentSnapshot was nil.
            print("Document does not exist")
        }
    case .failure(let error):
        // A `MyObject` value could not be initialized from the DocumentSnapshot.
        print("Error decoding city: \(error)")
    }
}
```

I don't understand where I made a mistake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Needs to be

```
docRef.getDocuments { (querySnapshot, error) in }
```

See here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#execute_a_query

Answer (score 1):

You are using method `getDocument` on `Query` object which does not have such method.

I think that this must be misunderstanding. Guessing from variable name `docRef` you wanted to assign to it `DocumentReference` object ([reference](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/swift/firebasefirestore/api/reference/Classes/DocumentReference)) than the method would work. However in presented code sample `docRef` is result of `whereField` method which returns `Query` ([reference](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/swift/firebasefirestore/api/reference/Classes/Query#wherefield_:isequalto:)). Even if the `Query` result with just one document you have to use appropriate method.

So there are 2 ways of correcting this:

1. You need to use `getDocuments` and rewrite whole function inside to loop over list of documents (as I can see currently the function is for `DocumentReference`).
2. Change the assignment to something like: `let docRef = myDataBase.collection("LogIn Codes").document(<document id>)` ([reference](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/swift/firebasefirestore/api/reference/Classes/CollectionReference#document_:))
   which give you `DocumentReference` object, but you have use exact id. This might be a problem, as I can see you are getting the id later in the code.

Anyway the issue is with using method from `DocumentReference` on `Query` object.